# Is there a way to make a HTML link that would run a program from local computer?

Tags: html, command-line

For debugging purposes it'd be nice if I could make my error page display clickable file names in exception stack traces that would [open them up  in my favorite editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350323/open-a-file-in-visual-studio-at-a-specific-line-number). However this would require me to execute a full command line - a simple link to a file will not do. Can this be done?

The solution can be IE-only and it can use techniques that require full trust (I don't expect it to be otherwise anyway). People are only going to use this on localhost, I will in fact disable this functionality when viewing the page remotely.

Comment: Hesitant to close this as a dupe of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1738573/easiest-way-to-execute-local-file-from-firefox because of the Firefox focus, but the accepted answer is what I would answer here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a new protocol to Windows as outlined [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(VS.85).aspx) .

This is especially nice because it works across browsers, and doesn't require any browser specific settings.

Just be careful with it - adding a new protocol handler opens potential, although very remote, vulnerabilities. When setting this up, never let the incoming URL be somehow a parameter to a generic command interpreter (like `cmd`). Always link it to an existing application that is not able to do anything destructive, not even through command line switches.

Comment: Hooray! It will do! :) It says here that I will be able to accept your answer in 5min, so I'll so it then.