# How to Open a Shared File on Client from Web Application?

Tags: java, javascript, asp.net, html, iis

I am developing a web application that will need to open a log file on the client side by clicking a button on a web page.

Please note this application is accessed through a company Intranet, the log file is hosted on a network drive and is shared with all the users. This means that every user can browse to the log file using the file explorer. If it wasn't because of browser security I could have just said:

```
window.open('file://192..1/Logs/My.log'); // and the file would have opened in the default app on the client
```

However this only works locally and blocked if the page is hosted.

I am not able to use HTML5 as all of the users are on IE6/7 and an upgrade is not possible. and to make things more difficult, client should not download the log file from the server so that's not a solution I am afraid. (this is the shortest way I could explain all this without writing a full page, please just accept the conditions.)

I would appreciate if anyone could suggest a way(s) to solve this.

Comment: Can the web server access the shared file directly itself?

Comment: Related: [Easiest way to execute local file from Firefox?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1738573)

Comment: so, why shouldn't the client download it? are you just saying you want it viewable in the browser? if the client is ever going to view the thing it has to be "downloaded" in some way

Comment: where is Java related to this question?

Comment: @hhamilton if the file is available on a local filesystem path, it makes perfect sense to want to open that directly instead of a downloaded copy, say if you want to edit it

Comment: There may not be a way to solve this, except if you can make IE6/7 trust the site enough to open the link.

Comment: @Pekka웃 it doesn't seem like the log file is local, from the question

Comment: @hhamilton it seems to be on a network drive (ie. accessible locally, even though not really local)

Comment: the file is on network drive, downloading the file is not an option. anyone knows how to ovveride the browser to open the file? this is in an enterprise environment so there's no problem with asking users to trust the web app.

Comment: @BrOSs as in Java Applets.

Comment: You can try adding the site to the highest trust level "zone" in the security settings. I can think of no other way